# Why is none of my CSS working?

Tags: html, css

So my layout (a club layout designed for a particular part of a website) was working fine, and then I added a background image and none of the stylesheet has worked at all. I've read over it like 5 times and cant see the error myself it may be something so simple and probably a complete rookie error but help would be much appreciated!

http://collabedit.com/98yhh  -  The Code

http://www.marasites.com/?name=iSell&page=divinitynewlayout  -  Live Site

Oh and ignore the extra CSS that isnt being used yet about to implement and fix all that up. Thanks!

Comment: You're missing `<html>` tag!

Comment: Not enough explanation of the problem . Code should be here, I should not have to go to another website to understand your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should validate your site before posting here: https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.marasites.com%2F%3Fname%3DiSell%26page%3Ddivinitynewlayout&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have a new line after your first quotation. Keep it in one line.

```
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/lfnb83g.jpg");
```

Comment: There has to be a line, the site breaks links that dont.

Comment: Yes, but don't manually enter. The site will still treat it as one line even though it looks like two.

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
                        background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/lfnb83g.jpg");
```

On to one line and it works fine!